# What is your reading recommendation to get back to mathematics?

Tags: book-recommendation

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question. If it's not please redirect me to the appropriate location.

First, a little bit of background.
I studied mechanical engineering and even got my degree more than 15 years ago. I never worked in the field since then so almost all the knowledge I got at that time just vanished.
I recently stumble on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/about) and I thought I'll give it a try. Both to get back with mathematics and to improve my coding.

Here come the question.
What resources (books, web-sites) do you recommend to get back with mathematics? I'd like to have sufficient knowledge to be able to do basic electronics.
Here is the list of things I would like to understand again:

- derivative
- integral
- differential
- series
- complex number

To achieve that, I started watching [NumberPhile](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A/videos). It is a nice channel but the theory is not explained as deeply as it could be in a book. My guess is to keep people interested.

Comment: I highly recommend "elementary analysis" by Kenneth A Ross.  Make sure to read the proofs if you really want to get a handle on it.

Comment: You might also check out the [Calculus Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus). Unfortunately, it is still missing sections, so it would only be a start.